# React component not re-rendering and showing CSS change upon value changing

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a React component that is dependent upon data from an external database at the moment.

What I want it to do is map through the data, and render a list of given components on the screen. It does this successfully.

However, I also want it to change its own appearance, based upon a function that an input executes when clicked on.

This input is a checkbox, that changes a value from false to true, or true to false, depending upon whether it's checked or not.

If the input is checked (i.e. true), then the component should add two properties - one to the overall container div by changing its background color, and the other to a paragraph tag by adding a strikethrough text decoration to it.

The value successfully changes when the input is clicked upon - if the value is false, it changes to true, and if the input is true it changes it to false.

However, once the input is clicked upon once, it no longer changes the styling. I essentially want it to continually change depending upon the value - not just once.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Why is the CSS not continually changing, and only changing once?

Note - this is only a portion of my overall component. This isn't the full file - it's just a part of what's being rendered. Not sure if that impacts things.

Here's my component code:

```
const SubTasks = ({ subTasks, setSubTasks }) => {
    const [individualTask, setIndividualTask] = useState("")

    const pushTask = () => {
        setSubTasks([...subTasks, {task: individualTask, completed: false} ])
        setIndividualTask("")
    }

    return (
        <div className="subtasks-container">
            <label className="subtasks-label">Sub Tasks</label>

            <div className="subtasks-box">

                {
                    subTasks.map((task, key) => {

                        const setCompleted = () => {
                            if (task.completed === false) {
                                task.completed = true
                            } else {
                                task.completed = false
                            }
                        }

                        return (
                            <div className={task.completed ? "subtasks-task-container container-completed" : "subtasks-task-container"}  key={key}>
                                <div className="create-sub-task-checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" value={task.completed} onClick={setCompleted} />
                                </div>
                                <div className="create-sub-task-title">
                                    <p className={task.completed ? "create-task-completed" : ""}>{task.task}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="create-sub-task-controller">
                                    <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        )
                    })
                }

                <div className="individual-task-input-container">
                    <input className="individual-task-input" type="text" value={individualTask} onChange={event => setIndividualTask(event.target.value)} />
                    <div className="create-task-button-container">
                        <button className="individual-task-button" onClick={pushTask}>Add</button>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.subtasks-task-container {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 5px 0;
    border: 2px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.container-completed {
    background-color: #a5e1ad;
}

.create-sub-task-title p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.create-task-completed {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

Comment: can you please share how `subTasks` is initialized?

Comment: Sure - I've put the full component in now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with state? I have not run below code but just give some hint, you can modify it if required.

```
subTasks.map((task, key) => {
    const [getTask, setTask] = useState(task);

    const setCompleted = () => {
        if (getTask.completed === false) {
            setTask({...getTask, "completed": true});
            console.log(getTask.completed)
        } else {
            setTask({...getTask, "completed": false});
            console.log(getTask.completed)
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className={getTask.completed ? "subtasks-task-container container-completed" : "subtasks-task-container"}  key={key}>
            <div className="create-sub-task-checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" value={getTask.completed} onClick={setCompleted} />
            </div>
            <div className="create-sub-task-title">
                <p className={getTask.completed ? "create-task-completed" : ""}>{getTask.task}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="create-sub-task-controller">
                <i className="fas fa-ellipsis-h"></i>
            </div>
    </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: Because I'm mapping through the array to display the list of tasks, I can't use state unfortunately as it'd be within a callback and hooks can't be used in a callback.

Comment: Is it possible to create new sub component inside map loop and there you can follow as above?

Comment: Hope you tried your code with this:  useEffect(()=>{      },[individualTask]) @JonNicholson